# Wireless driver profiling on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, profiling, driver

Since I'm new here i'll try to be as specific as possible,

I'm working on a project revolving around the ath10k wireless driver on ubuntu linux 12.04 64-bit where I have to profile the aforementioned driver.

I know that it is a kernel module so using gprof won't do any good. So my question is:

Is there any way to profile specific (if possible) functions in the wireless driver on ubuntu 12.04?

Should i do it by hand? (by adding extra code to keep track of the total time each function runs or something like that?)

thanks in advance!